# URL Rewrite with Custom Variables

Tags: url-rewriting, taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I right now have a custom post type with a url structure like:

```
example.com/videos/taxonomyname/
```

I have a custom variable that I am detecting in the template file to switch layout views which works fine but the URLs are setup like:

```
example.com/videos/taxonomyname/?template=g
```

I am wanting the URLs to look like

```
example.com/videos/taxonomyname/g/
```

Mainly because of pagination is not working properly with `?template=g` when you try and page it sets the URLs as

```
example.com/videos/taxonomyname/page/1/?template=g
```

which then returns a 404.

I have read some of the [past](http://matty.co.za/2009/11/custom-url-rewrites-in-wordpress/) [articles](http://scratch99.com/wordpress/development/how-to-change-post-template-via-url-parameter/). However was unable to get the URLs working properly partly due to the taxonomy name.

How can I get this right?